# Is there any predefined varible or any API that can provide me the PR Tag in my ci pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

I am having 2 pipelines, one is pr pipeline and second is ci-pipeline.
Also, having 2 branches, one is feature branch and second is main branch(having policy that direct merge to main branch is not permitted).

I am making changes in feature branch, and for merging the same changes to main branch, I am creating Pull Request.
The moment Pull Request is created, it will automatically trigger the pr pipeline(due to branching policy).
Also, when I am completing the Pull Request, it will automatically trigger the ci pipeline (as I have set the trigger to main branch for ci pipeline).

In pr pipeline, I am using an API that is fetching the the PR Tag using Powershell task.

Now, I want to use the same PR Tag in my ci pipeline as well.

Is there any predefined varible or any API that can provide me the PR Tag in my ci pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CI pipeline, you may still need to use the API that you have used in the PR pipeline to get the PR Tag.

The main question for this case is how to get the PR number (**`pullRequestId`**) in the CI pipeline and  pass it to the API URI for use.

The API should be "[**Pull Request Labels - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-labels/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)".

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/labels?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

After you completed merging the PR, the new commit generated on the main branch  generally has the message with the format like as "**`Merged PR {PR number}: {PR title}`**".

[image]

In the CI pipeline, you can use the predefined variable '**`Build.SourceVersionMessage`**' to get the commit message. then you can try to pick up the PR number from the message string for use.

Comment: Yes, I picked the PR number from the message "Merged PR {PR number}: {PR title}" and it is working as expected in ci pipeline.